# Why the user is not getting added to parse? Please see details

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have downloaded the parse sdk & have integrated it in my app following the tutorial.

The problem is that after running the app when I pressed the test button on the website, it said "**No user data yet...**"

**Here's `ParseApplication.java` file's code**:

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.initialize(this, "confidential", "confidential");

        ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
        user.setUsername("my name");
        user.setPassword("my pass");
        user.setEmail("email@example.com");

// other fields can be set just like with ParseObject
        user.put("phone", "650-555-0000");

        user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
                } else {
                    // Sign up didn't succeed. Look at the ParseException
                    // to figure out what went wrong
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**Here's `build.gradle` file's code**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.chenupt.android:springindicator:1.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1+'
}
```

I'm unable to figure out where is the problem.

Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at `ParseException` in sign up callback?

Comment: No. This is just what I followed from tutorial of adding the first user.

Comment: Then, put a breakpoint or log what is happening inside `public void done(ParseException e)` method.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem.

By adding just `android:name=".ParseApplication"` to the `application` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`, the problem got solved & I stored my first user in Parse.

Peace.